# Why am I getting a blank screen because of my server (ReactJS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, terminal

In, `Terminal`, I used `http-server` on the appropriate directory so that I can see my practice web app in action as I hit `cmd + s` -> `cmd + r`.  Today, I decided to continue it but I can't.

On server `http://192.168.1.8:8080`, my page appears normally.  But when I make changes to it and then do `cmd + s` -> `cmd + r`to check it out, nothing changes.  Everything just stays the same.

On server `http://127.0.0.1:8080`, the page is just completely blank.  Even when I try to make changes to it, nothing happens.  Just a blank screen.

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <title>My practice web app</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.16/browser.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="firstBar"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Here's my `index.js` file:

```
var Website = React.createClass({

   scrolling: function() {
     $('html,body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(".scrollToPortfolio").offset().top
        },'slow');
   },

   scrollToAbout: function() {
     $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(".scrollToAbout").offset().top
     },'slow');
   },

  render: function() {
    return(

      <div className="container">
      <kbd className="fullName">My practice web app</kbd>
        <button onClick={this.scrolling} type="button" className="btn btn-primary portfolio">Portfolio</button>
        <button onClick={this.scrollToAbout} type="button" className="btn btn-primary about">About</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary contact">Contact</button>

        <div className="trainPic">
        <img src={"./pictures/myPic3.JPG"} className="myPic"></img>
        </div>

        <div className="scrollToPortfolio">
          <h1>Portfolio</h1>
            <img className="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg"></img>
            <img className="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg"></img>
            <img className="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg"></img>
            <img className="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg"></img>
            <img className="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg"></img>
        </div>

        <div className="scrollToAbout">
          <h1>About</h1>
          <h2>Text</h2>
          <h2>Text</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Website/>, document.getElementById('firstBar'));
```

Here's are my `Terminal` servers:

```
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
http://127.0.0.1:8080
http://192.168.1.8:8080
```

Here's the error I'm getting on the blank page (`http://127.0.0.1:8080`):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.js: Unexpected token (19:2)
at Parser.pp.raise (browser.js:2027)
at Parser.pp.unexpected (browser.js:2596)
at Parser.pp.expect (browser.js:2590)
at Parser.pp.parseObj (browser.js:1447)
at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (browser.js:1250)
at Parser.parseExprAtom (browser.js:26392)
at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (browser.js:1097)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (browser.js:1079)
at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (browser.js:1035)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (browser.js:1018)
```

Comment: In the blank page, when inspecting using the browser, are there are any javascript errors?

Comment: @DavidNeto Yes there are!  I'll post it in right now, I meant to post that originally.

Comment: Your render method returns what should be a string but the compiler is going to interpret as variables because you don't enclose in either single or double quotes.

Comment: @scrappedcola what I had was working yesterday, now when I tried today, it's just blank.

Comment: when you reload the page and click on the console error, it will point you to a line in your code, could you copy that line and paste it here so we can have a look?

Comment: Are you using sourcemaps? `Uncaught SyntaxError: http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.js: Unexpected token (19:2)` checkout line `19` column `2`

Comment: @DavidNeto I already did, check my original post.

Comment: @Hitmands nope, not using sourcemaps.

Comment: What is <kbd>My practice web app</kbd> tag means?

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov It's a bootstrap style of text, check it out on w3schools.

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov can you replace the kbd tag with something else (for example <span></span>) and check if you still get errors?